# Angular 2 upload multiple files

Tags: html, angular

I trying to upload multiple files (PDFs or various image formats). Right now uploading a single file works, but multiple does not.

This is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <label> Upload PDF(s) or Images (PNG/JPG/DICOM/DCM):</label>
    <div class="ctrl">
        <div class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-file-image-o"></i>
        </div>
        <input type="file" (change)="onChange($event)"/>
        <md-input class="ctrl" [(ngModel)]="fileName"></md-input>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
onChange(event: any) {
    this.fileName = event.srcElement.files[0].name;
}
```

Help me how to do multiple files upload.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the `multiple` attribute to you input:

```html
<input type="file" (change)="onChange($event)" multiple />
```

And to show all file names in your input, do it like in this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/WvkNbwXpAkD14r417cYM?p=preview

```js
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <input type="file" multiple (change)="onChange($event, showFileNames)" />
      <input #showFileNames />
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

  onChange(event: any, input: any) {
    let files = [].slice.call(event.target.files);

    input.value = files.map(f => f.name).join(', ');
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Or use your variable instead of putting it directly to that input!

Comment: Showing, yes.. Cause you are using `files[0].name` .. but uploading? that was the question, right? :)

Comment: What I am trying is, I have a file upload option. Where I can upload one or more files. When I click on Add button it has to send that uploaded files names. Right now only the newly uploaded file name is showing.

Comment: @mxii If i want to upload it using HTTP which vallue should i send?

Comment: Can anyone tell me what is the angularJS code to upload multiple files ?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this it worked for me ;)

https://github.com/jkuri/ng2-uploader

Answer (score 1):

**Initialization:**

```
selectedFiles: File[];
```

**Files Selection Event :**

```
onFileSelected(event) {
  this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
  for (let i = 0; i < event.target.files; i++) {
    this.selectedFiles.push(event.target.files[i]);
  }
}
```

**Form Submission Event :**

```
onSubmit() {
  const formData = new FormData();
  if (this.selectedFiles.length > 0) {
   for (const row of this.selectedFiles) {
     formData.append('document_files[]', row);
   }
  }
}
```

**HTML File Input :**

```
<input 
 type="file" 
 id="documents" 
 multiple
 formControlName="documents" 
 (change)="onFileSelected($event)"
 accept="image/*,.pdf,.doc,.docx,.xml">
```