# Angular 2 simple directive file upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some simple directive for styling file upload in Angular CLI, only problem i have is that i use ID, and my directive works when is single on page, but when i have several upload fields of course it will not work.

Here is my code

**upload-field.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { TooltipModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tooltip';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-upload-field',
    templateUrl: './upload-field.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./upload-field.component.scss']
})
export class UploadFieldComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() labelName = 'Blader';
    @Input() placeHolderValue = 'Kies bestand';

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
    uploadButton() {
        const inputValue = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('upload-button')).value;
        const filename = inputValue.replace(/^.*\\/, '');
        (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('upload-file')).value = filename;
    }

}
```

**upload-field.component.html**

```
<input id="upload-file" placeholder="{{placeHolderValue}}" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" />
<div class="file-upload">
  <span class="btn btn-default btn-lg">{{labelName}}</span>
  <input id="upload-button" type="file" class="form-control upload-button" name="upload_file" (change)="uploadButton()" />
</div>
```

Comment: If you are looking for uploading multiple files, please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39608660/angular-2-upload-multiple-files

Comment: This is not multiupload, only problem is that i have when i have several component on  one page it doe not work

Comment: If you can please add a little more context, like how do you end up with multiple upload inputs, do you add them programatically or do you have them in html already? Because if they are static on the page you can simply rename them, and if they are implemented on button click or something again you can make a counter variable and pass it like id="upload-file-{counter}" so you can distinguish them.

Comment: I dont need multiupload filed, where does that say?? I only need this component to work when i have several of them on page??