# Upload multiple files: Angular

Tags: javascript, php, angular

I'm trying to upload multiple files but I have an error somewhere which I don't know yet. the thing is nothing shown in the console but the 'uploadData' is empty as shown below:

```
const uploadData = new FormData();
uploadData.append('File_1', this.selectedFile_1, this.selectedFile_1.name);
uploadData.append('File_2', this.selectedFile_2, this.selectedFile_2.name);
uploadData.append('File_3', this.selectedFile_3, this.selectedFile_3.name);
uploadData.append('File_4', this.selectedFile_4, this.selectedFile_4.name);
uploadData.append('File_5', this.selectedFile_5, this.selectedFile_5.name);
uploadData.append('File_6', this.selectedFile_6, this.selectedFile_6.name);
uploadData.append('File_7', this.selectedFile_7, this.selectedFile_7.name);
```

also have this function to check for any change on every input:

```
 selectedFile_1: File;
 onFileChanged_1(e) {
    let target = e.target; 
    this.selectedFile_1 = target.files[0];
    console.log(`first file changed: ${this.selectedFile_1}`)
  }
```

now, I am sending a lot of stuff to the PHP everything is ok except this. When I try to send one file it works, but, if I send multiple files the 'uploadData' doesn't get a single value. I also did console log it and i got nothing, totally empty (that goes in the backend too).

[image]

can anyone help plz?

Alright this might help, when I wrote it like this it worked but only for a single file I can't seem to do more than 1:

```
  uploadedData: FormData;
  selectedFile: File;

  onFileChanged(e) {
    let target = e.target;
    this.selectedFile = target.files[0];
  }

  eventId: Number = 0;
  upload() {
    const uploadData = new FormData();
    uploadData.append('myFile', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
    this.http.post<Response>(environment.apiUrl + "handers/events/imageUpload.php", uploadData).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.eventId = data.id;
        Swal.fire(
          'Téléchargement Terminé!',
          '',
          'success'
        )
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: Does this help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39608660/angular-2-upload-multiple-files.

Comment: No sorry, I'm trying to upload multiple files but not on the same input, each file is in its own input field that's the difference.

Comment: Do you have different onFileChanged methods ?

Comment: yes like this onFileChanged_1, onFileChanged_2, onFileChanged_3...

Comment: I have suggestion to make . I believe because of re-rendering of the page the file1 , file2 variables are getting set as undefined . Could you please make a service and keep adding the uploaded files there and when you click the upload button , loop over the files and append to the form data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to go around this, the thing is that you can't send multiple files in one API call to PHP with Angular, in other words, you have to send these files one by one and that's the solution for the problem, hope this helps.