# Upgrade logic to async upload multiple files - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

At this point i realized that i need to send images to backend one by one, it can be only image1, only image2, or both, the problem i have is if i need to send 5 files... this logic is not the best option, how can i improve this code to handle async operations? How can i create a FileList from different inputs in Angular? Thanks in advance.

User component:

```js
this.userService.updateUser(this.userDetails).subscribe(
      response => {
        if(response.user){    

          if(this.filesToUpload1 && this.filesToUpload2){
            this._uploadService.makeFileRequest(Global.url + "/upload-user-image-logo/" + response.user._id, [], this.filesToUpload1, 'image')
            .then((result:any) => {
              this.userDetails = result.user;
              this.filesToUpload1 = null;              
                this._uploadService.makeFileRequest(Global.url + "/upload-user-image-banner/" + response.user._id, [], this.filesToUpload2, 'image')
                .then((result:any) => {
                  this.userDetails = result.user;
                  this.filesToUpload2 = null;          
                });                                                                    
            });
          }

          if(this.filesToUpload1 && !this.filesToUpload2){
            this._uploadService.makeFileRequest(Global.url + "/upload-user-image-logo/" + response.user._id, [], this.filesToUpload1, 'image')
            .then((result:any) => {
              this.userDetails = result.user;
              this.filesToUpload1 = null;                                             
            });
          }

          if(this.filesToUpload2 && !this.filesToUpload1){
            this._uploadService.makeFileRequest(Global.url + "/upload-user-image-banner/" + response.user._id, [], this.filesToUpload2, 'image')
            .then((result:any) => {
              this.userDetails = result.user;
              this.filesToUpload2 = null;          
            });          
          }       
                      
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log(<any>error);
      }
    );
```

```js
  fileChangeEvent1(fileInput: any): void{
    this.filesToUpload1 = <Array<File>>fileInput.target.files;
    this.imageLogoStatus = true;
    if(!this.filesToUpload1.length){
      this.filesToUpload1 = null;
      this.imageLogoStatus = false;
    }
  }

  fileChangeEvent2(fileInput: any): void{
    this.filesToUpload2 = <Array<File>>fileInput.target.files;
    this.imageBannerStatus = true;
    if(!this.filesToUpload2.length){
      this.filesToUpload2 = null;
      this.imageBannerStatus = false;
    }
  }
```

Upload Service:

```js
makeFileRequest(url: string, params: Array<string>, files: Array<File>, name: string){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let formData: any = new FormData();
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            
            if(files != undefined){
                for(let i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
                    formData.append(name, files[i], files[i].name);
                }          
                xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
                    if(xhr.readyState == 4){
                        if(xhr.status == 200){
                            resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                        } else {
                            reject(xhr.response);
                        }
                    }
                }
                xhr.open('POST', url, true);
                xhr.send(formData);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 upload multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39608660/angular-2-upload-multiple-files)

Comment: It doesn't.. i need to use individual inputs

Comment: So when you say "later I have to send 5 files" you mean you'll have 5 separate input elements? And there could be 1 to 5 elements each with a single file?

Comment: correct sir, because each file has an unique tratement in server side.

Comment: It would be more efficient to capture. them separately, but send them all to the server with one request. That request could be accompanied by an object literal identifying each image and it's server treatment. So collecting them would look the same (a bunch of input elements), but there would be a single function to asynchronously send everything at once.

Comment: That's a good idea, i edited my question. I'm getting the files this way, how can i create a FileList to send an Array of files?

Comment: The correct way would be creating an array of fileList like: [FileList, FileList, FileList] and then append each item to a formData ?